# Memory Usage Traversing own LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, memory-management

I am currently trying out implementing my own String Class (in Java) and to start I decided to represent a String as a LinkedList of Character Nodes that I can then Traverse and modify. I haven't had trouble with this as the implementation is similar to that of LeetCode's and I've done a few problems on there. My Question is that when traversing the String/LinkedList, I typically allocate a sort of pointer List that contains the same data but I manipulate from there, as the list is singly linked so once I go forward I cannot go back. I want to know if there is a way to deallocate the memory or have it sort of freed up after i have used the pointer list to get the job done, would I need to call System.gc() after I am done or will things naturally be cleaned up. I am curious because I am pretty sure the runtime of the actual methods are not too bad, but I dont want for the memory to become a problem as time goes on. Anything helps, thank you.

As I am currently trying to implement the String Class I am trying to avoid the uses of things like built in ArrayList<>() or LinkedList<>(). I have done most of the work iteratively but i don't know if maybe recursion would be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

> nd to start I decided to represent a String as a LinkedList of Character Nodes that I can then Traverse and modify.

This is inefficient to an astonishing degree.

Assuming a 64-bit JVM:

All objects know a little bit about themselves (such as what class they are), in addition to, of course, storing the value of each field.

Thus, for a string with 200 characters in it:

- Linkedlist spends 64-bit on its identity, then another 64 on the pointer to the head node. (128)
- Each node in your linkedlist is an object, thus, knows a bit about itself (64 bit), and contains a field with the character. Objects are, by virtually all JVMs, aligned on 64-bit boundaries, so even though that one field would appear to only take 16 bits (the width of `char`), it actually ends up taking 64. That's 128 bits per node, times 200 characters, is 3200 bytes.
- Except, it possibly gets a lot worse if you are using e.g. a `Node<Character>` instead of a node object specifically written for `char` primitives: In that case, your nodes are 128 bit (64 bit for itself, 64 bit for the pointer to the character wrapper object), then the character wrapper is itself also 128 bit. For a total of 6400 bytes.

Thus, depending on how you wrote it, that string of 200 characters takes 6416 or 3216 bytes, and consists of 201 or 401 objects, possibly scattered around the heap, thus causing a simple loop through each character to chain together multiple page faults, each taking 500 or more CPU cycles. (CPUs can't even read main memory anymore these days. All they can read is the cache pages on the CPU die itself. These hold a fraction of all memory in chunks called pages. If you attempt to read from memory that isn't in one of the on-die cache pages, a page fault is emitted, the CPU core halts, the memory controller is tasked to flush out the entire page that has been least recently used back to main memory, then load in an entire page (the one that contains the memory you want to read), and only then can the CPU continue. Hence, for fast ops, you want all memory accesses needed during that op to come from 1 or 2 pages tops. Arrays, such as the `byte[]` used by java's own String, are guaranteed to focus on contiguousness (it's all next to each other). A linked list structure does not get that guarantee, however).

Contrast to java's built-in strings which, if they are simple ASCII, occupy 200 bytes (1600 bits) total for the entire string, plus 64 bit for the string object, plus 64 for the string object's pointer to the data, plus another 64 for some bookkeeping (efficiencies which your class also does not have, such as memoizing the hashcode). A total of 216 bytes. That's less than 5% of the memory requirements of your solution.

Ouch.

> My Question is that when traversing the String/LinkedList, I typically allocate a sort of pointer List that contains the same data but I manipulate from there, as the list is singly linked so once I go forward I cannot go back. I want to know if there is a way to deallocate the memory or have it sort of freed up after i have used the pointer list to get the job done, would I need to call System.gc() after I am done or will things naturally be cleaned up.

In the face of that incredulous inefficiency, this question is **wildly** missing the point. It's like worrying about the sea levels in Manhattan rising if you spit into the ocean off the coast of Amsterdam: You're a few thousand ballparks removed from that being in any way noticeable.

Generally, for performance, it matters, or it doesn't. Almost always it just doesn't. For the vast majority of applications, literally 99% of the total resources (CPU and RAM are generally the important ones) are spent on less than 1% of the total code. The so-called 'hot path'. Generally optimizing code that isn't in the hot path **does absolutely nothing whatsoever** - it is entirely unnoticable. Often "optimizing" locks in behaviours and complicates APIs, which makes it harder to change the code that flows into, and out of, the thing you optimized. Hence, **optimizing the not-hot-path is BAD for performance**, because if ever you *do* start working on the hot path, you'll find it's a lot harder to adjust the paths that flow into and out of it, as you've been wasting your time 'optimizing' the irrelevant parts.

If this string stuff is in the hot path, you have to toss the whole thing out and find a solution that scores a little better than literally over 30x worse than java's baked in strings. If this string stuff isn't in the hot path, none of this is relevant in any way.

Either way, worrying about a temporary list you track during a traversal, isn't what you should be thinking about. It's either a lot worse (you have to toss all this out and find another way), or a lot better (it's not on the hot path and it doesn't matter).

> would I need to call System.gc() after I am done or will things naturally be cleaned up.

`System.gc()` is a hint. It may do nothing. System.gc() cannot affect what java can collect. Whatever would be cleaned by a call to `System.gc()` is by definition something that java will get around to cleaning up on its own.

> but i don't know if maybe recursion would be a better way to go about it.

highly doubtful; especially on JVMs, recursive solutions are pretty much never anywhere near the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, although Nodes were something that were familiar to me you helped point out that that is not the approach to take and that there are other things I needed to take into account. Thanks.

Comment: You are somehow mixing bits and bytes: _occupy 200 bytes total for the entire string, plus 64 bit for the string object, plus 64 for the string object's pointer to the data, plus another 64 for some bookkeeping [...] A total of 392_: A total of 392 bits or 392 bytes?

Comment: @ThomasKläger Indeed, I messed that up. I edited these errors away, and as a consequence the 'how bad is this' dropped from 'Over 100x worse' to "merely" 'over 30x worse' - but trying to put such an absolute number on the cost of having your nodes smeared all over the heap is much more difficult.